# How can you set up Unit Testing(qUnit) with an SAPUI5 Application?

Tags: unit-testing, sapui5, qunit

I'm trying to implement unit testing within my SAPUI5 Application. I understand how to perform the unit tests --but I'm not understanding how to configure the testing in my  SAP UI5 application. I believe the problem is how I'm attempting to load in the controller I want to test. I have a basic tree structure like so:

[image]

I'm unfamiliar with how to set up the tests. When I insert the following controller, I get a script error:

**test.js**

```
sap.ui.require(["../Controller/Main.controller.js"],

 function(MyController){
     //Quint code
     test("hello test", function(assert) {
      assert.ok(1 == "1", "Passed!");
    });
});
```

**initialTest.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>QUnit Example</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.15.0.css">
          <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                    src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js">
          </script>    
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.15.0.js"></script>
          <script src="tests.js"></script>
          <script src="/Controller/Main.controller.js"></script>          
          <script>
          </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="qunit"></div>
      <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**screenshot of the error**

[image]
 [image]

How can I properly load in the controller.js that I would like to test?

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Comment: Brackets, I've also used Eclipse but their auto generating file definition model is outdated so I'd like to stick to writing this from scratch

Comment: @Kode_12 did you manage to find a way to solve this? I'm also looking for the same and stumbled upon your query here. Please update the answer if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try including like this

```
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("controller", "../Controller");
jQuery.sap.require({
     modName : "controller.Main",
     type : "controller"
});
QUnit.test("Some text", function() {
     var oCont = sap.ui.controller("controller.Main");
});
```